# How can I create a DataGridView displaying tables in restaurant

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

[image]

Hello, I am codding a restaurant automation to improve myself.
I have a table called tables in the database.
I can fetch data as shown in the left datagridview. but I
could not split into columns like on the right  datagridview
I hope I can explain.

```
  private void FrmAnaEkran_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        VerileriGetir();
    }

    private void VerileriGetir()
    {
        Veritabani vt = new Veritabani();
        vt.ConnectionOpen();
        vt.SqlQuery("select * from masalar");
        DataTable dt = vt.GetDataTable();
        vt.ConnectionClose();
        List<masa> masalar = new List<masa>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            masa m = new masa();
            m.adi = dr[1].ToString();
            masa.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
            masalar.Add(m);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < masalar.Count; i++)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = masalar[i].adi;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in grid view data will be displayed in rows, try to use Listview which is more suitable in your case.

Comment: The line… `dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = masalar[i].adi;` … is only going to put values into the first column … `Cells[0]`… If you want all four cells to be filled per row then you will need another mechanism such that the code assigns Cell[0], Cell[1], Cell[2] and Cell[3]. It is unclear “why” you are doing this this way. It is always better to assign a data source to the grid as opposed to adding the items row by row.

Answer (score 1):

Use GroupBy :

```
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Masa", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_4" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_5" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_6" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_7" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_8" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_9" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_10" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_11" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_12" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Masa_13" });

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().Select((x, i) => new {masa = x.Field<string>("Masa"), index = i}).GroupBy(x => x.index / 4);

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column4", typeof(string));

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
                int col = 0;
                foreach(var row in group)
                {
                    newRow[col++] = row.masa;
                }
            }
```